# Subdomain showing incorrect content when going through HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, apache, cpanel, cloudflare, vhost

I have a domain on my server called `example.com` and I set up a subdomain called `links.example.com`. Whenever I go to `links.example.com`, the domain is pointing to the same directory, even though in the cPanel settings, I told it to go to `/public_html/links` instead of just `public_html`

What's weird is whenever I go to it through non-HTTPS, it points to the correct directory that I need it to go.

I do not have a .htaccess file setup yet. I read online that you can fix the issue by adding an SSL cert to that subdomain, but because I'm using cloudflare's SSL, I don't have an SSL cert to provide.

**So for clarification:**
http://example.com - shows content from /public_html/ (as it should)
https://example.com - shows content from /public_html/ (as it should)
http://links.example.com - shows content from /public_html/links/ (as it should)
https://links.example.com - shows content from /public_html/ (which it shouldn't)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue using a cheap workaround. If anyone knows of any better, feel free to answer as well.

The issue was, there was no virtualhost for that subdomain for SSL. cPanel won't make a virtualhost unless there's a cert installed for that domain. I made a self-signed cert and installed it for that subdomain.

Since I'm using cloudflare's SSL, the self-signed doesn't matter, and the virtual host is now listening on port 433 meaning that SSL works properly for that subdomain.